# ReactJS properly updating state with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started working with reactjs recently and I need to know how to properly update my state.

My actions.js:

```
export function updateCreateCampaignObject(data) {
  return {
    type: actions.UPDATE_CREATE_CAMPAIGN,
    payload: data,
  }
}

export function updateCampaignProducts(data) {
  return {
    type: actions.UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCTS,
    payload: data,
  }
}

export function updateCampaignTarget(data) {
  return {
    type: actions.UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_TARGET,
    payload: data,
  }
```

My reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  campaign_dates: {
    dt_start: '',
    dt_end: '',
  },
  campaign_target: {
    target_number: '',
    gender: '',
    age_level: {
      age_start: '',
      age_end: '',
    },
    interest_area: [],
    geolocation: {},
  },
  campaign_products: {
    survey: {
      name: '',
      id_product: '',
      quantity: '',
      price: '',
    }
  }
}

export default function createCampaignReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_CREATE_CAMPAIGN:
      return { ...state, state: action.payload }

    case UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCTS:
      return { ...state, campaign_products: action.payload }

    case UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_TARGET:
      return { ...state, campaign_products: action.payload }

    default:
      return state
  }
```

In this case, I only want to add +1 to quantity in my campaign_products object.
Do I need to create an action just for this?

How can I call this action in my component, something like this?

```
import { updateCampaignProducts as updateCampaignProductsAction } 
from '~/store/modules/createCampaign/actions'

  function addQuantity() {
    dispatch(updateCampaignProductsAction({
      survey: {
        quantity: quantity + 1
      }
    }))
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not tested, But you need to change something like this. (3 steps)

1) Change quantity to number

```
  campaign_products: {
    survey: {
      name: '',
      id_product: '',
      quantity: 0,
      price: '',
    }
  }
```

2) In Reducer, based on action update the state from current state. (in your case not depend on any action payload)

```
export default function createCampaignReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {   switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCTS:
      const current_quantity = state.campaign_products.survey.quantity;
      return { ...state, campaign_products: current_quantity + 1}
    default:
      return state   }
```

3) dispatch action

```
  function addQuantity() {
    dispatch(updateCampaignProductsAction())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with or without hooks.

both ways, read the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) about connecting redux to react. 
react team wrote npm library to connent them.

Comment: hello Yosi. My redux is already working, I have another simple reducer that is working, but this one I have nested objects, hence the doubt

Comment: when you connect the redux store to your component - you have access to the global state from the component's props. with that, you also have the dispatch function in the props. you just pass the action to the dispatch. you can import the action creator from another file.